# Galaxy Buds microphone not recognized

Tags: bluetooth, microphone

I'm trying to use the microphone from my Galaxy Buds in Ubuntu 18.04 but they don't show up in the input section.

I already tried to install blueman and change the profile to HSP/HFP but it doens't do nothing.

`pacmd` shows the `headset_head_unit` profile but it says that isn't available

```
index: 5
    name: <bluez_card.CC_21_19_BF_B3_1B>
    driver: <module-bluez5-device.c>
    owner module: 51
    properties:
        device.description = "Galaxy Buds (B31B)"
        device.string = "CC:21:19:BF:B3:1B"
        device.api = "bluez"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.form_factor = "headset"
        bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_CC_21_19_BF_B3_1B"
        bluez.class = "0x240404"
        bluez.alias = "Galaxy Buds (B31B)"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
        device.intended_roles = "phone"
    profiles:
        a2dp_sink: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) (priority 40, available: unknown)
        headset_head_unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (priority 30, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: yes)
```

Trying to set it anyway fails.

```
> pacmd set-card-profile 5 headset_head_unit
Failed to set card profile to 'headset_head_unit'.
```

Its the same issue [reported here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085960/use-bluetooth-headset-with-microphone-hfp-in-ubuntu-18-04), but the answers gave no solution

Answer (score 2):

Builded and installed pulseaudio from sources - solved this problem, microphone working ok ([link to build pulseaudio from sources](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/Developer/PulseAudioFromGit/)) 
But got time to time sound distortion for some reason during playback.