# Ofono obstacles wiith bluetooth headset mic

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, microphone

I'm trying to get the mic on my galaxy buds+ to work with my ubuntu 18.04 setup (on xps 7390). [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085960/use-bluetooth-headset-with-microphone-hfp-in-ubuntu-18-04) describes my problem more or less; it seems common. I followed that to [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1223200/12717). I encountered two obstacles which I don't know how to bypass. I can't comment there because I'm new to Ask Ubuntu (and new to linux in general, for that matter) and don't have the reputation. Anyway, first, at step 3, I don't know what to look for in the output to recognize if I even have a modem already there (so I don't know whether the subsequent steps are valid for me). Second, assuming they are valid for me, when I followed that, I got this: "Gtk-Message: Failed to load module 'canberra-gtk-module'". So I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed). Then I tried step 4 again and got nothing, I entered the command into terminal and nothing came back. Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue with Oneplus Wireless Z Bass edition. My headset microphone was not detected by PulseAudio and the problem is that my headphones  don't have HSP profile, only HFP profile. After trying for 2 days, I came to the solution of replacing PulseAudio with Pipewire sound server, which supports HSP, HFP and A2DP by itself. So there will be no need to install any other utility like `ofono`, `phonesim`. Also, to be noted that my problem wasn't resolved even after following all the steps to configure `ofono` in PulseAudio. So I came up with the steps to replace PulseAudio with PipeWire.

Here is the detailed article I have written to resolve this problem, the steps of which I'm also adding here. You can follow it and most probably be able to solve your problem.

[Bluetooth headset microphone not detected](https://atish3604.medium.com/solved-bluetooth-headset-mic-not-working-detected-in-ubuntu-20-04-86a5236444d0)

Open your terminal and follow these steps:

1. We will use a PPA for adding Pipewire to Ubuntu 20.04, which is maintained regularly:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream
   ```
2. To update the PPA packages in your system do:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Install the package:

   ```
   sudo apt install pipewire
   ```
4. There is also a dependency needed to be installed with Pipewire, otherwise you will face the issue of *“Bluetooth headset won’t connect after installing pipewire”*. Install the dependency by:

   ```
   sudo apt install libspa-0.2-bluetooth
   ```
5. Now, to install the client libraries:

   ```
   sudo apt install pipewire-audio-client-libraries
   ```
6. Reload the daemon:

   ```
   systemctl --user daemon-reload
   ```
7. Disable PulseAudio:

   ```
   systemctl --user --now disable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
   ```
8. If you are on Ubuntu 20.04, you also need to “mask” the PulseAudio by:

   ```
   systemctl --user mask pulseaudio
   ```

I am not sure but, if possible, you can try to run this on other versions too.
9.     After a new update of Pipewire, you also need to enable `pipewire-media-session-service`:

```
   systemctl --user --now enable pipewire-media-session.service
```

10. You can ensure that Pipewire is now running through:

    ```
    pactl info
    ```

    This command will give the following output, in Server Name you can see:

    ```
    PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.28)
    ```

    Things should be working by now and you can see your microphone.

If it doesn’t show up, then try restarting Pipewire by this command:

```
systemctl --user restart pipewire
```

If it’s still not showing your microphone, you can try rebooting once and remove and pair your Bluetooth device again to check if it works now.

I hope I have helped you solve your problem.

If you want to rollback all the changes we did, you can do it by using:

```
systemctl --user unmask pulseaudio
systemctl --user --now enable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
```