# Enable bluetooth headset microphone support in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone, 21.04

There is no microphone selection option in the general audio settings interface. Only the notebook's built-in microphone is displayed. There is a selection for headphones, i.e. headphones with a microphone are connected to the system. I can hear the sound.

Outputting device information

```
2 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 23
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "sof-hda-dsp"
        alsa.long_card_name = "sof-hda-dsp"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a0c8"
        device.product.name = "Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        HiFi: Play HiFi quality Music (priority 40768, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <HiFi>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_5__sink/#1: Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller HDMI3 Output
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_4__sink/#2: Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller HDMI2 Output
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_3__sink/#3: Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller HDMI1 Output
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__sink/#4: Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller Speaker + Headphones
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_5__sink.monitor/#1: Monitor of Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller HDMI3 Output
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_4__sink.monitor/#2: Monitor of Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller HDMI2 Output
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_3__sink.monitor/#3: Monitor of Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller HDMI1 Output
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__sink.monitor/#4: Monitor of Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller Speaker + Headphones
        alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__source/#5: Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller Headphones Stereo Microphone
        alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_6__source/#6: Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller Digital Microphone
    ports:
        [Out] HDMI3: HDMI3 Output (priority 700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                
        [Out] HDMI2: HDMI2 Output (priority 600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                
        [Out] HDMI1: HDMI1 Output (priority 500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                
        [Out] Speaker: Speaker (priority 100, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                
        [Out] Headphones: Headphones (priority 200, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                
        [In] Mic2: Headphones Stereo Microphone (priority 200, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                
        [In] Mic1: Digital Microphone (priority 100, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                
    index: 2
    name: <bluez_card.18_95_52_44_01_F8>
    driver: <module-bluez5-device.c>
    owner module: 26
    properties:
        device.description = "1MORE ComfoBuds Pro"
        device.string = "18:95:52:44:01:F8"
        device.api = "bluez"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.form_factor = "headset"
        bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_18_95_52_44_01_F8"
        bluez.class = "0x240404"
        bluez.alias = "1MORE ComfoBuds Pro"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
        device.intended_roles = "phone"
    profiles:
        a2dp_sink: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) (priority 40, available: yes)
        headset_head_unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (priority 30, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: yes)
    active profile: <a2dp_sink>
    sinks:
        bluez_sink.18_95_52_44_01_F8.a2dp_sink/#6: 1MORE ComfoBuds Pro
    sources:
        bluez_sink.18_95_52_44_01_F8.a2dp_sink.monitor/#8: Monitor of 1MORE ComfoBuds Pro
    ports:
        headset-output: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                
        headset-input: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
```

Here in the penultimate line I see that headset-input not available

```
    headset-input: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
```

how to make the headphone microphone available for selection?

```
jekson@machine-head:~$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 40:1C:83:8D:D6:04  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 96:6
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:1058550 acl:187 sco:0 events:110817 errors:0
    TX bytes:63926682 acl:95904 sco:0 commands:9535 errors:0
    Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0x0f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'machine-head'
    Class: 0x3c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer, Audio
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 5.2 (0xb)  Revision: 0x3236
    LMP Version: 5.2 (0xb)  Subversion: 0x3236
    Manufacturer: Intel Corp. (2)
```

**bluetooth info**

```
jekson@machine-head:~$ sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-10-06 12:02:26 WEST; 3h 2min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1209 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18795)
     Memory: 2.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1209 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

окт 06 12:02:26 machine-head systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
окт 06 12:02:26 machine-head bluetoothd[1209]: Starting SDP server
окт 06 12:02:26 machine-head bluetoothd[1209]: Bluetooth management interface 1.19 initialized
окт 06 12:02:35 machine-head bluetoothd[1209]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.115 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
окт 06 12:02:35 machine-head bluetoothd[1209]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.115 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
окт 06 12:02:55 machine-head bluetoothd[1209]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_connect_cb() connect to 18:95:52:44:01:F8: Device or resource busy (16)
окт 06 12:02:57 machine-head bluetoothd[1209]: profiles/audio/avctp.c:avctp_control_confirm() Control: Refusing unexpected connect
окт 06 12:03:00 machine-head bluetoothd[1209]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_18_95_52_44_01_F8/sep1/fd0: fd(40) ready
окт 06 13:06:21 machine-head bluetoothd[1209]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_18_95_52_44_01_F8/fd1: fd(39) ready
окт 06 13:39:59 machine-head bluetoothd[1209]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_18_95_52_44_01_F8/fd2: fd(39) ready
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the profile you have chosen in the Bluetooth settings?

Comment: @David attached settings pictures

Comment: **1infern0** answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085960/use-bluetooth-headset-with-microphone-hfp-in-ubuntu-18-04  help me

Comment: Simple fix. That profile gives good sound NO MIC. Change to the HSP profile not as good sound but both sound and mic.

Comment: replaced Pulseaudio with Pipewire yet, Didn't know about this dependency before

Answer (score 0):

**In theory**, you should just go to `settings` and:

1. Select in `Output` your bluetooth device
2. Select in `Configuration` the `HSP` profile instead of `A2DP`
3. Now  in `Input` you would see your bluetooth device!

But this doesn't seem to work in 20.04.

=> So follow instructions in https://atish3604.medium.com/solved-bluetooth-headset-mic-not-working-detected-in-ubuntu-20-04-86a5236444d0 (also shown on [Use Bluetooth headset with microphone (HFP) in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085960/use-bluetooth-headset-with-microphone-hfp-in-ubuntu-18-04) but with a mistake as of August 2023).

Now, you will be able to choose between

- `Handsfree`: lower quality but both input/output
- `Headset`: high quality but only output