# Bluetooth earbuds turning off after 5 minutes

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I have the Tronsmart Spunky Beat True Wireless Bluetooth Earbuds, which works fine for Windows and Android, but turns off exactly 5 minutes after paired on Linux. Until that point, it works fine and I cant switch to HSP and cant use the mic.
Does anyone know a driver, a workaround or anything I could use?

I checked the Arch Wiki :) with no help, disabled pulseaudio auto-turn-off device on idle feature and restarted pulseaudio, but it's still doing this.

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 and kernel version 5.3, and I tried Ubuntu 18.04, too.
Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and got it working finally

Reference:

1. [Bluetooth profile locked to A2DP (high-quality audio sink) but cannot change to HFP/HSP (low-quality bidirectional headset)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985615/bluetooth-profile-locked-to-a2dp-high-quality-audio-sink-but-cannot-change-to/1223200#1223200)
2. https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-failed-to-change-profile-to-headset_head_unit/
3. https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/eg2q7v/bluetooth_earbuds_turning_off_after_5_minutes/fv3v8nk?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3 
   (**u/ugurbor**'s comment)
4. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset#HFP_not_working_with_PulseAudio

And thanks to u/ugurbor who helped me even in inbox.

once it starts working, you have to execute the commands on boot as a script

```sh
ofono-phonesim -p 12345 /usr/share/phonesim/default.xml &
# sleep 0.05;
sudo service ofono restart;
# sleep 0.05;
~/ofono/test/enable-modem /phonesim;
```

enable the sleep if required, It works for me without sleep 
**Easiest way to test if it started working without waiting for 5 minutes to headsets power off is to check `pavucontrol`***, if HSP/HFP is available (If it says (unavailable) then your earbuds will turn off after sometime as usual.

[image: Screenshot of pavucontrol when HSP/HFP is working]

### IMPORTANT THINGS TO NOTE:

1. I am not sure these are all the steps required to make it work because I have tried a long time to fix it and succeded recently, I tried to replicate it on another laptop with linux mint and **FAILED** (It shows no modem).

***So it would be REALLY APPRECIATED if someone makes a step by step process to get it working from scratch after fresh distro installation.***

2. For some reason I could never make it work as a systemd service, even if the service works fine, the service started on boot fails (IDK) how and needs restart to work. 
   So I just
   run the script with `gnome-session-properties` aka Startup Applications in gnome .
3. Since I couldn't replicate it on mint help on creating modem is appreciable since I don't exactly remember all the things (from beginning) I did which actually made it work.
   **This problems needs a step by step clear fix since lot of people face this. Maybe someone could make a script which can automate this because this is a pretty silly bug which annoys a lot**